# Too many columns specified in Dask data frame

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I am calling the following data frame [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231492/importing-large-csv-file-using-dask) and after following the answer at this section, I tried to compute the dataset to read into memory:

```
computed_result = dask.compute(dataset)
```

I get the following error:

> ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 6 and found 3

To make sure I have the right amount of columns:

```
year                 int64
species             object
occurrenceStatus    object
individualCount      int64
decimalLongitude     int64
decimalLatitde       int64
dtype: object
```

Any idea as to why I am getting this error - have I gone wrong during the `Dask.dataframe` part of my code, and I should specify more clearly or in a different way `usecols`? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The column loading appears to be correct. To check that the error is not at the step of creating the dask dataframe, try running: `dataset.head()`. If that shows a `pandas` object, then the dataframe was created correctly.

Comment: ```dataset.head``` loads the dask dataframe, however ```dataset.head()``` returns the same warning as given above. Though, the object that is returned is the same as that given in the link previously. Only the column headers are given, with ```...``` for values.

Comment: Hmm, check the column separator, is it comma? If not, you will need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: If you mean adding the separator here: `dataset = dd.read_csv(file_path, names=cols,usecols=[9, 18, 19, 21, 22, 32], sep=",")`, then it gives the same error.

Comment: Well, it looks like dask/pandas is not able to parse the 6 columns correctly. Usually this is because of some quirk in csv formatting, so I would check the separator and quoting (by inspecting parts of the csv file).

Comment: I cannot check the csv file directly as it is far too large for me to open with any editor; are there ways to check this in python - what commands should I call?

Comment: There definitely is some issue involved here, as when I re-ran my jupyter environment and run the code, the error changes to: ```ValueError: Unable to parse string "3162074496 4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e URN:catalog:CLO:EBIRD:OBS892558907 Animalia Chordata Aves Columbiformes Columbidae Zenaida Zenaida macroura  SPECIES Zenaida macroura (Linnaeus" at position 0``` It seems some of this content is not part of the column `species` - I know this because I can just at least 4GB of the first few data in R.

Comment: it looks like a tab separated file, so you can try passing `sep="\t"`

Comment: I think you are right and after making that shift, the error changes to: ```ValueError: Unable to parse string "Animalia" at position 0

/Users/X/Conda/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/core.py:121: DtypeWarning: Columns (2) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))``` Though I am unsure what this means

Comment: As suggested: add `dtype='str'` or `low_memory=False` as options when loading csv.

Comment: I have included ```dtype={'species': str}``` into the Dask Dataframes which removes that warning however, ```ValueError: Unable to parse string "Animalia" at position 0``` still remains, and I cannot seem to figure this one out?

Comment: That does help, however, I had to change `year`to numeric so that I can filter by year - which actually works. It is currently still running and I think that it may work better than before, though I will probability have to configure column two again perhaps into category to suppress the warning, as the warning is given when its an `object`