# How to load big csv file using dask and parallel processing and then convert back to pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dask

I have `30GB` of .csv data. I am using dask to load the data into chunks and then use compute on top of it.

**Code**

```
%%time

import dask.dataframe as ddf
import dask.multiprocessing

df1 = ddf.read_csv("raw_data.csv", blocksize=1000000)

df2 = df1.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

**Error Output:**

```
TypeError: The get= keyword has been removed.

Please use the scheduler= keyword instead with the name of
the desired scheduler like 'threads' or 'processes'

    x.compute(scheduler='single-threaded')
    x.compute(scheduler='threads')
    x.compute(scheduler='processes')

or with a function that takes the graph and keys

    x.compute(scheduler=my_scheduler_function)

or with a Dask client

    x.compute(scheduler=client)
```

How can I get rid of this error or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Right now the code will try to load the whole data into memory, which is not ideal. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68231655/10693596

Comment: I find that the message tells you *exactly* what you need to do. However, this will indeed load the whole thing AND be slower than pandas alone, because you are serialising the whole thing to copy between processes.